# Deriving posterior distribution of multivariate normal

Tags: self-study, bayesian, multivariate-analysis

I have a problem that I can't seem to solve:

The prior: $\beta_h \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{\beta},D)$.

Somehow the posterior is $\beta_h \sim \mathcal{N}(M, \Omega)$, where $M=(D^{-1}+X'X)^{-1}(D^{-1}\bar{\beta}+X'p)$ and $\Omega=(D^{-1}+X'X')^{-1}$, where $X$ is a data matrix and $p$ is a data vector.

How can I prove $M$ and $\Omega$ are as such? What would be the likelihood function? I have 7 similar 'derive' questions that make no sense to me.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include mathematical text formatting (Mathjax, which is basically LaTeX). Please double-check that I have not inadvertently introduced any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this is for a regression model,

$p = X\beta_h +\varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I)$

Without explicitly specifying the model (which should be in your question, not my answer), you have no hope of proceeding.

From that, you should be able to write down the density for $\varepsilon$ and hence for $p$, and from that, the likelihood in terms of $\beta_h$.

From that, you should be able to write down an expression for the posterior (up to scaling constant), complete the square in $\beta_h$ and recognize the density.

This is pretty standard Bayesian manipulation.

Comment: +1 "Complete the square" is the key idea.  I suspect that phrase would correctly answer several dozen related questions that have appeared on our site :-).